# Adobe Acrobat Pro make all pages the same dimension

Tags: adobe, acrobat

Does anyone know how to change the dimensions of each page on an Acrobat document.
Also how can I see the dimensions of each page seperately??

For example I have a 3 pages document. The first 2 pages are of the same dimensions 8.2 x 11.6 inches. However the 3rd is smaller. How do I make it larger?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

With **Mac OS X** and the more recent versions of **Acrobat Pro**, the *PDF printer* option does not work. What does work is doing basically the same thing in *Preview App*. Open the multi page file in Preview, select File>Print. In the Print dialog set your sheet size as if you are using a printer. You may want to select "*Auto Rotate*", "*Scale to Fit*" and "*Print Entire Image*". Then in the lower left corner is the drop button "*PDF*" and in that menu select "*Save as PDF*".  Give it a new file name, click Save and then you can open the resulting file in whatever PDF app you want and the sheet sizes are the same.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Saving a PDF file when printing is not supported. Instead, choose File > Save."

Answer (score 11):

You have to use the Print to a New PDF option using the PDF printer. Once in the dialog box, set the page scaling to 100% and set your page size. Once you do that, your new PDF will be uniform in page sizes.

Answer (score 5):

- Open  the PDF in MacOS´ Preview App
- Chose *File* menu –> *Export as PDF*
- In the export dialog klick the *Details* button an select your page size
- Click save

All pages of the resulting document will be scaled to that size. The resulting file size is nearly identical to the original PDF, so I conclude, that image resolutions/compressions are not changed.

**Hints:**

1. I am not sure whether the "Export as PDF" menu item is available by default or only if Adobe Acrobat is installed.
2. My first trial was to use Preview App and print (!) into a new PDF, but this leads to additional margins around the page content.

Comment: This was simple and confirmed worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

The page sizes are looking different in your PDF because the images were originally set to different DPI (even if images are identical HxW in pixels). The good news is - it's only a display issue - and can be fixed easily.

An image with a higher DPI value would display smaller in a PDF (displays at the 'print-size' of the image). To avoid this, open each image in an image editor like GIMP or Photoshop. Open relevant image print control dialog box and set a suitable uniform DPI info for all the images. Remake the PDF with these new images. If in the new PDF images are too big - redo the DPI setting for each to a higher value. If in the new PDF pages are too small to read on-screen without zooming, again - redo DPI adjustment, this time put a lower DPI value. Ideally, 150 DPI should be good enough for images of 2500X2500 pixel - on a 17 inch monitor set to 1366x768 resolution.

BTW, the PDF file shall print each page at the specified DPI of that page. If all images are same DPI, you'll get a uniform printing.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 It works! Actually I've used a handy web app to change the DPI metadata of images before inserting them into PDF: https://convert.town/image-dpi

Answer (score 0):

The above works,(having an original document with mixed pages of 11' and 16' wide). 
However auto rotate needs to be off otherwise landscape pages are saved with page white top and bottom, so dont work in full screen view.

Solution is to re open the new PDF in acrobat and crop the first image (carefully to avoid white border), then select page range i.e. all,  this then applies to  all pages.
job done !